# Is ini_set("memory_limit", "512M"); too much?

Tags: php

I am using 2 php libraries to serve files- `unzip`, and [`dUnzip2`](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2495-PHP-Pack-and-unpack-files-packed-in-ZIP-archives.html)

zip    zip.lib
http://www.zend.com/codex.php?id=470&single=1

They work fine on files under 10MB , but with files over 10MB, I have to set the mem limit to 256. With files over 25MB, I set it to 512. It seems kind of high... Is it?

I'm on a dedicated server- 4 CPU's and 16GB RAM - but we also have a lot of traffic and downloading, so I'm kind of wondering here.

Comment: So what *exactly* do you have to do to upload an `11MB` file?

Comment: not upload , download , we serve over 1K of files that range from 1MB to 30MB

Comment: setting a high limit doesn't mean php will take up that much ram each time, it just means that it won't go OVER that limit, if it does start using extra memory.

Comment: thank you mark , now should I also set the ini_set("max_execution_time", "600");  higher ? what my script does is licensing files before user downloads

Comment: I would think if you store the actual zip file somewhere in your servers, which mean you dun require an additional to zip/unzip file on the fly, then you would serve the page without consuming too many memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're using php to load the whole files into memory before serving them to the user? I've used a function found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php (comments section) that serves the file in parts, keeping memory low. Copying from that post (because my version is changed):

```
<?php 
    function readfile_chunked ($filename,$type='array') { 
      $chunk_array=array(); 
      $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk 
      $buffer = ''; 
      $handle = fopen($filename, 'rb'); 
      if ($handle === false) { 
       return false; 
      } 
      while (!feof($handle)) { 
          switch($type) 
          { 
              case'array': 
              // Returns Lines Array like file() 
              $lines[] = fgets($handle, $chunksize); 
              break; 
              case'string': 
              // Returns Lines String like file_get_contents() 
              $lines = fread($handle, $chunksize); 
              break; 
          } 
      } 
       fclose($handle); 
       return $lines; 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> what my script does is licensing files before user downloads

Generally you should avoid any web script that consumes that much memory or CPU time. Ideally you'd convert the task to a run via a detached process. Setting a high limit isn't bad per se, but it makes it harder to detect poorly written scripts and easier for high demand of the complex pages to hurt performance across even the simple pages.

For example, with [gearman](http://pecl.php.net/package/gearman) you can easily set up some license worker scripts that run on the CLI and communicate with them via the gearman API.

This way your web server can remain free to perform low CPU and memory tasks, and you can easily guarantee that you'll never run more than X licensing tasks at once (where X is based on how many worker scripts you let run).

Your front end script could just be an AJAX widget that polls the server, checking to see if the task has completed.

Comment: cant run PECL on my server :(

Comment: @Benn, that's just one suggestion that I'm familiar with. You could easily do it yourself via a queue table in your database. And none of this is to say setting a high limit is bad (particularly if you do it just for that page), but personally I prefer a more robust solution in this case.

Comment: well yes , me to , it is only increased (files required ) once the user click's on download button. but it just does not sit well with me that I have to set it high . we did not have issues in the past 4 years but getting ready for new site version and want to cleanup the codes

Comment: but queue table is not a bad idea either but than again , im hitting the DB harder than I should

Comment: could I hire you for the job ?